# Child UserControl TextBox value in Parent UserControl WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a parent `UserControl` that has a `Button`. On `button_click` a child `UserControl` is added into Parent `UserControl`. That newly added Child `UserControl` have a `TextBox`.
Now, Parent `UserControl` has another `Button` when clicked i want to get the value of `TextBox` of child `UserControl`. How can i get that ?

Plus, let's say the child `UserControl` added on RunTime are more than 1. Then how can i get `TextBox` value of all of these child UserControls ?

**EDIT and UPDATE !**
**Child UserControl have this method**

```
    public string GetText()
    {
        return ProductNameBox.Text;
    }
```

**Parent UserControl have this**

```
    public List<UserControl> UserControlList = new List<UserControl>();

    public void NewProductModule(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            AddProductModule productModules = new AddProductModule();                
            UserControlList.Add(productModules);
    }
```

**And This method**

```
    private void PreviewPdfFunc(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (UserControl cnt in UserControlList)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cnt +" Total = " + StackPanelContainer.Children.Count);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think the question is too broad to give you answer. If your requirements to get the data of a single textbox which is placed in each user control which further loaded in each parent user control. There are many ways you can do it, but does all your user controls be available for you at a time from parent user control?

Comment: You can have a list of UserControl in your code behind and then when ever a user control is added at run-time, add to the list.

Iterate through the list and read the textbox value. But it sounds very bad way of coding for me.

This is all just information, you can try it out.

Comment: @GK i am trying the second method as you told . and as below someone has suggested that as an answer . but  i am getting an error that  have mentioned in comment ! please see

Comment: I see you use a list of UserControl and add an object with the type AddProductModule. Might this be the problem?

Comment: @Shmosi i changed that to `public List<AddProductModule> UserControlList = new List<AddProductModule>();`   still problem is same !!!

Comment: Did you Change the type in the foreach loop

Comment: yes as you can see in above code ! `foreach (UserControl cnt in UserControlList)`

Comment: OH ALLAH !!!!! thank you brother for your help .Really appreciate ! stay blessed ..This line worked ! `foreach (AddProductModule cnt in UserControlList)`

Comment: update your answer and i will mark it as answer !!!!

Comment: I did, and always check if you have the correct type when you code, especially when you alter the code many times. Like I said in my comment, I still use var in foreach and wonder why it won't work ;)

Comment: @Shmosi ahahah ..thank you so much ! i will keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, add every `AddProductModule` you create to a list (because you have to store them somewhere)

```
List<AddProductModule> AllControls = new List<AddProductModule>();
AllControls.Add(YourItem);
```

Second, you have two Options to get the text

First: Set the button to public

Second: Create a public method which you can call from your Parent, for example

```
public string GetTBText()
{
    return TextBoxExample.Text;
}
```

In the end, to get all Texts, you could

```
foreach(AddProductModule item in AllControls)
{
    string ValueOfTB = item.GetTBText();
}
```

***EDIT***

There was the Problem, that a wrong object type was in use, which made Problems with my answer. Formerly, the type was not AddProductModule, instead it was UserControl, and before that it was var (which was the main Problem to begin with)

If you come here, you should now be able to run the code in my answer without a problem

Comment: on this line `item.GetTBText()` ..it says UserControl does not contain a defination for GetTBText

Comment: although i have added this `GetTBText()` method in child UserControl

Comment: anything to say about this?

Comment: @hammas_Stack Have you set the method to public?

Comment: `var productModules = new AddProductModule();` `UserControlList.Add(productModules);`

Comment: this is how i am adding newly created control into list !

Comment: @hammas_Stack Oh I see! The Problem is that there is `var item in`. I always get this Problem myself in `foreach` loops. The code now doesn't know how to interpret `var` yet and only gives a few opportunities. Change the `var` to `UserControl` and you should be fine (I'll update my answer)

Comment: @hammas_Stack please provide your code, instead of bits of line statements. It helps to see and address issue easily.

Comment: @Shmosi  NO ! problem is nat just `Var` i have used alternative ..And please see updated Question !

Comment: @hammas_Stack I left a comment to your question